# Implementing a Non-Wrapping, Count-Based Multi-Select Dropdown with MUI Chips

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the `MUI library` for a project that involves a `multi-select dropdown` with `chips` representing the selected data. The functionality is working well, but I'm encountering an issue with responsiveness: the chips are wrapping onto multiple lines. What I would like to achieve is a design where, instead of wrapping, it displays a text like `"+2 more"` or `"+3 more"` at the end when there are more items than can fit in a single line. I'm not sure how to implement this feature in MUI. Could anyone provide assistance or guidance on how to achieve this in MUI?

Code Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-multiselect-sp4sg3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C13

I have attached my output and my required output images.
[image]
[image]